# Word 2016: Continuous break causes page break

Tags: microsoft-word

Using Word 2016, I hit the problem "Section break causes an unexpected page break in Word" which is described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/292074

The MS KB says the KB applies through Word 2007. But I found the resolution also applies to Word 2016.

Is there a better way to do my documents to avoid this? Was a total PITA to fight for awhile, and then find that it is a documented issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I find that the linked article explains it due to footnotes, but I find it occurring in a document that has no footnotes or endnotes. But does have 2 columns. In Word 2016 for Mac.

Comment: please take a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

IN Word 2010, I used the fix MS suggests, compatibility layout footnotes like Word 97 etc, but it was still giving a next page break.
However, if I put the continuous break on a paragraph break and then make that paragraph hidden, success, i get a new section without a new page. 
This way I can put different page headers while using continuous breaks without always needing a new page